# I accidentally deleted my android phones system app

Tags: applications, system

Anyone can help me on how to restore system apps like HOME.apk, i accidentally deleted it so the phone is stuck on boot, cant go to its home, my phone is a goophone4s thanks ...

Comment: 1. Don't use all bold text. Emphasizes should be used to highlight words, not entire posts. 2. restore your backup which you did before starting modifications.

Comment: 3. You can also try to push any launcher from the playstore's web frontend, in the hope your device picks it up. If you only deleted your `home.apk`, that should help it starting up completely. In case you deleted more stuff, see my answer below and my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't take a backup before fiddling around with your system (which I assume is the case), you will have to get yourself the ROM (see: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575)) and flash it to your device.

Advice for the next time you start playing with system stuff: Backup your current ROM (which can be done via Custom Recovery as [nandroid](/questions/tagged/nandroid) [backup](/questions/tagged/backup)). So in case anything goes wrong, you simply need to boot into recovery and restore that backup, which includes the entire system and your user stuff as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install new ROM, but you lose your warranty permanently. Because the ROM is locked first time, when you re-install you unlock it. After re-locking it'll show your status as  *re-locked* instead of *locked* and it means you have no warranty any more. You must backup your phone before any system modification.

Comment: While the first 6 words are correct (without a backup), the remaining stuff is not: flashing a stock ROM provided by the manufacturer/vendor is perfectly fine and will *not* void warranty. OTOH, OP already voided warranty by rooting the device.

Comment: @Izzy: Yes and no. On some newer Samsung devices for example, Samsung have introduced the KNOX setting which allow them to tell if a particular Samsung device has a "Custom" ROM. Well, custom here means modified/rooted. So, even if you reinstall a stock ROM back onto a device, this KNOX counter will not automatically reset itself. You need a third-party app like TrianglAway to reset this setting so Samsung can't tell if the device has been previously modified/rooted. Judging by the OP's post, I would assume the OP has rooted his/her device previously in order to delete system applications.

Comment: Also, in some countries, it is perfectly legal now to root, modify, or jailbreak your device as long as it's for legal purposes, meaning - if you rooted your device in order to install pirated applications, then it is illegal, else legal. Manufacturers, like Samsung, etc, have been made by the courts to honour this as part of their device's warranty in countries where this law has been passed.

Comment: @ChuongPham OP didn't say he ever flashed a custom ROM (so that Knox-counter should not have been triggered, and re-installing an official stock ROM shouldn't trigger it). The other part (rooting) is already an established fact (regardless jusristical implications and whatever rules apply in his country, the device already *is* rooted). So please understand my comment as "if that voids your warranty, it's already done" :)

Comment: @Izzy: If you read my comment again, "Custom" means "customised" stock ROM, not custom ROM like Cynagenmod, etc. "Custom" is the label Samsung device displayed when it is rooted because the kernel checksum is not the same as the one shipped with the ROM. Since the OP has rooted his device, the KNOX counter would have already tripped. So "re-installing an official stock ROM" is not going to magically reset this KNOX counter - even third-party app like TriangleAway cannot reset this KNOX on some Samsung rooted devices.

Comment: OK, again in short words: "If the Knox-counter has not yet been tripped, installing a stock ROM won't trigger it either".

Answer (score 0):

1. If your phone starts up normally and does not have home screen alone
2. If you had enabled `adb debug`,

You can copy the APK for home (you should know the name as you deleted it [image]) from some one's phone of same model having same version of ROM as yours.  Then you can connect your phone to your PC and use `adb install` commands to install the home launcher.

Answer (score -2):

Backup the phone and try to reset the phone. So that you`ll get all the apps which are coming with your phone.

Comment: Wrong. The `/system` partition is not touched on a factory reset, and that's where the pre-installed apps reside. As the app was deleted from there, a reset won't help.